# Save image to desktop from iframe tag

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I am using iframe tag to display image. Also there is a Save Image Button on page. I want that when user click the button, then the image inside iframe should save on desktop.
Remember i want only image to be saved on desktop not the whole page.
How to do this...

eg:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var now = false;
function saveIt() {
if (now) { document.execCommand("SaveAs"); }
}
</script>
</head>
<body önload="now=true">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="saveIt();" Text="Save" />
<br />
<iframe src="Images/findr.png" width="400px" height="400px" id="external" name="external"></iframe>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: follow this link http://simplyaspnet.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-save-images-in-database-and.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. I've tested this and working fine:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function saveIt() {
            imgURL = document.getElementById('external');
            if (typeof imgURL == 'object')
                imgURL = imgURL.src;
            window.win = open(imgURL);
            setTimeout('win.resizeTo(0, 0);', 100);
            setTimeout('win.moveTo(0, 0);', 200);
            setTimeout('win.document.execCommand("SaveAs")', 500);
            setTimeout('win.close()', 1000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="button" id="Button1" runat="server" onclick="saveIt();" 
               value="Save" />
        <br />
        <iframe src="Images/orderedList3.png" width="400px" height="400px" 
         id="external" name="external">
        </iframe>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...it is quite good...but i want to save this image in particular folder like C:\Images\New   i don't want that user select where to save this image.